# How to open a Foundation Reveal modal javascript

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation

I've been trying to follow the Foundation docs, but I really can't figure out how to open a modal window using jQuery. Here's what I have:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TRE7M/2/)

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="myModal" class="reveal-link">Name</a>

<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
      <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).foundation();
    $('a.reveal-link').trigger('click');
    $('a.close-reveal-modal').trigger('click');
 });
```

Thanks, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It depends on what version of foundation you are using. The latest version of foundation uses $('#myModal').foundation('reveal', 'open'); to open a reveal popup.  Older versions use $('a.reveal-link').trigger('click');  As @pcx mentioned, you are using the same ID for both the reveal-link and reveal-modal which would cause a javascript error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are mistakenly setting the same id on both the `<a>` and `<div>` tags.

Two ways to do this:

1. Your modal  has the id 'myModal', so you should set the attribute `data-reveal-id='myModal'` to your `<a>` tag. You've instead set `id="myModal"`, which you should remove. The JavaScript you are using should work with this change.
2. Change the `<a>` tag's id to `id="modalLaucher"` and then use:

   ```
   $("#modalLauncher").click(function (e) {
       $('#myModal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
   });
   ```

Comment: This might be outdated, refer to this question for a better answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855505/zurb-foundation-6-reveal-doesnt-work