# Zurb Foundation 6 Reveal doesn't work

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I've downloaded the new Zurb Foundation 6 complete package (**Foundation for Sites**). The archived file contains the following files and folders:

```
[css] > app.css, foundation.css, foundation.min.css
[img] > [empty folder]
[js]  >
  app.js
  foundation.js
  foundation.min.js
  vendor > jquery.min.js, what-input.min.js
```

I included the JS file in the footer and the CSS at the header:

```
<!-- foundation library and initialization -->
<script src="/Foundation/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

**Error in Chrome**

I try to use REVEAL component (it worked in Foundation 5), but this time it throws me an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: We're sorry, 'reveal' is not an available method for i.
```

I've looked inside the Foundation.min.js and it has REVEAL in it. I download the complete package, so it should work, but it doesn't.

**The JS code that should trigger the modal:**

```
$('#submit-modal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
```

**UPDATE 1:** Tried on a fresh page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="/Foundation/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">this is the body of the page</div>
     <div id="popup-modal" class="reveal-modal full" data-reveal aria-labelledby="pop-up-modal-title" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
         test
     </div>

<script src="/Foundation/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- foundation library and initalization -->
<script src="/Foundation/js/vendor/what-input.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Foundation/js/foundation.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The text of the popup appeared on the page, it's even not hidden by default, and I get an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: We're sorry, 'Reveal' is not an available method for Reveal` when trying to run the command:

```
$('#popup-modal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
```

From the console.

Foundation 6 is a fresh release, and I;ve might missed something. I upgraded to Foundation 6 from Foundation 5. Foundation 5 Reveal worked ok, but after changing to the new Foundation 6 some components start not working out.

I checked the Documentation and the initialization and classes are the same.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try with

```
var popup = new Foundation.Reveal($('#popup-modal'));
```

and then:

```
popup.open();
```

`$('#popup-modal').foundation('reveal', 'open');` doesn't work in Foundation 6 anymore.

Comment: Yep, and also they changed the class to 'reveal' instead of 'reveal-modal'. Works, thank!

Comment: indeed it will not work. The signature of foundation as a jQuery extension has changed to taking the first argument as the plugin, and the rest parameters as options to the plugin: https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/develop/js/foundation.core.js#L250:L284

Answer (score 23):

Chris from ZURB here. There's a couple of ways you can invoke methods on plugins, see: 
http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/javascript.html#programmatic-use

The easy "new" way now is

```
$('#exampleModal').foundation('open')
```

Comment: I ran into the same issue. I think it was, that the search on the internet referenced directly to the reveal-documentation from foundation 5, not 6.

Answer (score 4):

Both options provided by Juliancwirko & EddieDean are working. But there's a difference.

If you are using "**new Foundation**" approach and you also have **data-options** set like: data-options="closeOnEsc: false; closeOnClick: false;" **they won't have any effect**.

But if you are using foundation('open') they will work.